# NoClassDefFoundError on generated client library - GAE cloud endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have 2 endpoints in my GAE Java project. When I use the GPE eclipse plugin to generate the client library for my Android project, the code is generated without any errors. (I don't know why the generated code is in the package `com.google.api.services`).

The problem is, when I launch my Android app, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown for the class, `DeviceInfoEndpoint$Builder`, and the app crashes.

> This is after I updated the ADT and the GAE plugin to the latest
>   version. It was actually working well before that.

I even tried with the `endpoints.sh` script to generate the client library. Getting an `EntityExistsException` on that. I am literally struck now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this. right click on your project. gotto properties java build path. make sure you have check android private libraries for both your project and library project. clean and build

Comment: thanks @Raghunandan, I found this out just a minute ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than 2 days of dead stop, found out that I needed to check Android Private libraries and Android 4.2 in (Build path -> Configure build path -> Order and Import).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784945/902572